# What does Conan Doyle’s “at the Sydenham end of the road of that name” mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Can anyone tell me about the sentence from (Sherlock Holmes series) Norwood Builder by Conan Dolye?

> Mr. Oldacre is a bachelor, fifty-two years of age, and lives in Deep Dene House, at the Sydenham end of **the road of that name**.

Here, the last part, "the road of that name", is what I am unsure of.

My understanding is "at the Sydenham side of **Sydenham** road." But can this be interpreted as "at the Sydenham side of **Deep Dene** road" too?

Is what "that" indicates obvious here, or can it be ambiguous?

Comment: Please remember to always invert subject and verb in English questions

Comment: Sydenham Road runs through the district of Syndenham.

Comment: I lived there in the 1970s, briefly.

Comment: The novel states: the Sydenham end of the road of that name. So, that means a place and road with the same name, according to the sentence.

Comment: Factually I think all the commenters are right. But it could be ambiguous on a purely grammatical level.

Comment: Don't know about other parts of the world, but in much of the US it's common to have a road named, eg, "Taylorsville Road" which runs from the city of Louisville to the town of Taylorsville.  Thus "at the Taylorsville end of the road" would mean along the road, near Taylorsville.

Comment: @HotLicks, Indeed, and, "at the Taylorville end of the road of that name", means: there is a town and a road that have the same name. I feel like the only English speaker around (in this case).

Comment: Lambie, no-one has expressed a view contrary to that.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your answer is convoluted. Because you "kinda" say it and then you blockquote a sentence that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the house is at the Sydenham **end** of the road, not the Sydenham side.

I do not see any ambiguity. "Of **that** name" refers to the last preceding name, Sydenham. As confirmation, you may note that Doyle used an existing house in the story.

> Jonas Oldacre "lived in Deep Dene House at the end of Sydenham Road"

[The London of Sherlock Holmes By Thomas Bruce Wheeler](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E-i6BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT146&lpg=PT146&dq=deep%20dene%20house,%20sydenham%20holmes)

A picture is available, although since the house has been rebuilt, I do not know if what you can see is the 'staring brick' mentioned by Doyle, but I suspect it is the same type.

[Sydenham Road - 'Deep Dene House', Jonas Oldacre's house - rebuilt (picture)](https://www.flickr.com/photos/shsl/12259566356)

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

**

> Mr. Oldacre is a bachelor, fifty-two years of age, and lives in Deep
>   Dene House, at the Sydenham end of the road of that name.

**

Sydenham Road runs through the district of Syndenham.

Sydenham end of the Sydenham Road, as opposed to the Crystal Palace end of the Sydenham Road road, for example.

[Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sydenham,+London+SE26+6XN,+UK/@51.423366,-0.0743336,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x48760164ba3254ff:0x65da280e9a1aa948!8m2!3d51.42476!4d-0.059399)

Comment: @TimLymington  The answer chosen does not even answer the question properly. What is the matter with everyone?

Comment: In what way does it not answer the question properly?

Comment: It is not clear in your answer that there is a Sydenham Road and a place (district?) called Sydenham.